# Using tc4420 as buffer for IR2110 driver

Tags: mosfet-driver, gate-driving

[image]

Hey there,i want to keep this simple.
Recently ive been working on a half bridge tesla coil project.i have succesfully made circuits using the ir2110 gate driver itself but the reason why i come up with this circuit is i want better isolation between my driver circuit and the half bridge because im planning to use a pulse transformer for driving the gate of the mosfets.The IR2110 ic is not capable of driving the pulse transformer but the TC4420 however according to its datasheet its more suitable.i wanted to utilize the shutdown pin of the IR2110 gate driver for audio modulation.before soldering the components i wanted to make sure does this method work,
Im looking forward for opinions and suggestions,
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you have pin names on your IC pins?

Comment: Sorry about that im using phone and i used electric circuit studio app.the app doesnt have that much features

Comment: If you're going to be using pulse transformers for driving the gates you don't need bootstrapping and you could just use the TC4420 directly and get rid of the IR2110.

Comment: @unimportant ya thats more easier and simple but the problem is i wanted to utilize the shutdown pin of the ir2110 driver so that i can modulate the signal,perhaps any other suggestion for the modulation.i have an idea that uses some bjts arranged as a nor gate, so any opinion please ?

Comment: Run the control signal for the TC4420 trough a 2-input AND gate. The second input can then be used for modulation. That's a better way then using a shutdown pin anyway. Shutdown systems aren't meant to be used like that and often have certain limitations (such as speed).

Comment: @Unimportant okey i will make the circuit as said on a breadboard and update you.i think this is the answer for my question thank you very much